# servlets - synchronized access attribute at application scope

Tags: servlets, synchronization

```
// in a context listener
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        SessionListener.context = sce.getServletContext();
        HashMap<String, String> messages = new HashMap<>();
        context.setAttribute("messages", messages);
}
```

Now I want to access the messages map from various servlets - what about synchronization ?

Namely I want to add an element to the map (whose key must be unique) - so I have to try a couple of times maybe - except if there is some method in the java ee api (?)

EDIT : interested also in synchronizing access to a session scoped map

Comment: and what exactly is the question?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy:How should I synchronize the access to the map and if there is a way to generate a unique random string in the api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This map is a non-thread-safe object shared by multiple threads. So every access to the map should be synchronized. You have various options:

- have each client of the map synchronize on the map itself: very fragile
- use a thread-safe map like `Collections.synchronizedMap()` or ConcurrentHashMap. This will never let the map in an inconsistent state, but additional synchronization could still be needed for operations that should be atomic but involve several method calls on the map
- encapsulate the map into an object of your own, and make sure that this object provides all the necessary operations that need to be done on the map. These operations should of course perform the necessary synchronization.

The third solution is probably the best one. The second one might be OK if the operations on the map are very simple, and coveredby methods of the map.

Regarding the generation of unique and random strings, you could combine a [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) (for uniqueness) and a Random (or SecureRandom, depending on your requirements), for the randomness.

Comment: Thanks - will get back to you - should I sync on the servletContext object in cases 2 or 3 ?

Comment: You mean `HashMap<String, String> m = (HashMap<String, String>) request.getServletContext.getAttribute("messages");
    synchronized (m) {...}`. Would it be the same for a map which is a session attribute ? Meaning in both cases the same object will be returned in different servlets/threads ? You said this is "fragile". Looking into UUID |

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. It's very fragile, because instead of encapsulating behavior in a unique object, responsible for the thread-safety and synchronization, you force every user of the HashMap to know about the synchronization policy and implement it correctly. If one of the uses fails to do it correctly, you're doomed.